# $G_\delta$ set in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider a set $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $X$ is not $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Could $X$ still possibly be $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ in the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$? I would really appreciate an example if possible.

Edit: by $G_\delta$, I mean a countable intersection of open sets.

Effort put in so far: I have tried to come up with examples, but everything I can think of, has not worked.

Further edit: To be honest, I was actually trying to come up with an example of $X$ that contains both rationals and irrationals (my bad I overlooked the fact that I had not mentioned this explicitly). I am grateful for the answers though.

Comment: That $X=\bigcap_{i=1}^nO_i$ where $O_i$ are open for all $i$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ has the subspace topology?

Comment: @par Yes, I will edit the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - take $X=\mathbb{Q}$. $\mathbb{Q}$ is not $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (by the Baire category theorem), but $\mathbb{Q}\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})=\emptyset$ is $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

---

If we want $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, to rule out this sort of nonsense, then the answer is no. Suppose $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is $G_\delta$ relative to $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Pick open (in $\mathbb{R}$) sets $U_i$ such that $$X=\bigcap (U_i\cap(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}));$$ then $X=(\bigcap U_i)\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})$, but since $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is $G_\delta$ (exercise), $X$ is $G_\delta$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You beat me to it :-)

Comment: I further clarified the question, in case you have time to take another look. Thanks!

Comment: @anonymous Well, you can modify this in a number of small ways. Ex: let $X$ be the set of all rationals, together with the interval $[0, 17]$. Or, let $X=\mathbb{Q}\cup \{\sqrt{2}+k: k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Or etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you mean this or not. Rational no set $\Bbb Q$ is not a $G_{\delta}$ set but in $\Bbb R- \Bbb Q$ it is $\phi$ hence open so it is $G_{\delta}$.